# why won't gethash return my key's value?

Tags: elisp

Experienced lisp, scheme, clojure programmer making the move to elisp from python for automating routine, everyday, basic tasks: I got an enormous surprise from the following in `ielm`

```
ELISP> (setq h2 (make-hash-table))
#s(hash-table size 65 test eql rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ())
ELISP> (puthash "a" 1 h2)
1 (#o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
ELISP> (gethash "a" h2)
nil
```

huh?  The key and the value appear to be present:

```
ELISP> h2
#s(hash-table size 65 test eql rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ("a" 1))
```

/slaps forehead.  I must be missing something totally obvious. Info says:

```
-- Function: gethash key table &optional default
 This function looks up KEY in TABLE, and returns its associated
 VALUE—or DEFAULT, if KEY has no association in TABLE.
```

great.  Let's see if we can get `gethash` to return anything other than `nil`:

```
ELISP> (gethash "a" h2 'fubar) 
fubar
```

wow.  Ok, I'm a lot dumber than I thought.  What on earth am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

The default membership test for a hash table is `eql`.  If you'd like to use a string as the key, set it to `equal` instead:

```el
(setf hash (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
(puthash "a" 1 hash)
(gethash "a" hash)                      ; ==> 1
```

For reference, here's the relevant part of the docstring:

> `make-hash-table` is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> `(make-hash-table &rest KEYWORD-ARGS)`
>
> Create and return a new hash table.
>
> Arguments are specified as keyword/argument pairs.  The following
>   arguments are defined:
>
> `:test` TEST -- TEST must be a symbol that specifies how to compare
>   keys.  Default is `eql`.  Predefined are the tests `eq`, `eql`, and
>   `equal`.  User-supplied test and hash functions can be specified via
>   `define-hash-table-test`.

Comment: I guess technically you're not passing a symbol as the `:test` parameter in your example...

Comment: `string-equal` might have some advantages over `equal` if I know my hash-table has strings only as keys.  I am not sure why elisp has both `string-equal` and `equal`, because `equal` can be used any place that `string-equal` can be used modulo the fact that `string-equal` throws type errors when you don't give it strings.  Maybe that's a desired behavior.